# Java Hibernate - Wrong parenthesis in query

Tags: java, hibernate

In my function I created a condition like this:

```
and (o.status != :shipped or (o.status = :cancelled and sp.cancelledQt != sp.requestedQt))
```

If I enable query logging this condition becomes:

```
and (shipmentor0_.status<>? or shipmentor0_.status=? and positions1_.cancelledQt<>positions1_.requestedQt)
```

As you can see the parenthesis are in a different order than I wrote.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the result somehow affected?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the internal parenthesis is not necessary. The "And" operator precedence is higher then the "Or" operator. But you can keep it to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing.

Hibernate it's just taking advantage of the [distributive property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property) of the [logical disjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction#Properties) (fancy name for "OR") to redact your query in a more efficient way.

It is one of the pros of using an ORM instead of plain JDBC.